# Laravel link with session

Tags: laravel, session

I'm building a website with two season versions: winter and summer.

Now I have unordered lists with two links: winter and summer. Let's call it season navigation.

```
<ul class="season-navigation">
  <li><a href="/">Winter</a></li>
  <li><a href="/summer">Summer</a></li>
</ul>
```

The user opens the website. The default version now is winter and when it goes to some inner pages and after clicking the main logo of the website, it will take it to the winter homepage, like every website does.

But if a user clicks on the summer link and enter some inner pages and then clicks on the main logo of the website, I want the user to be taken to the summer homepage, not the winter homepage.

As far as I know, Laravel has very good API for sessions, but I'm not sure how to use them in this case.

My question is: when a user clicks on one of the season links, how to store that in session, so when clicks on the main logo of the website to be taken to homepage of the selected season navigation link?

Also, how to add class to the body (winter or summer) that depends from which link is clicked on the season navigation ?

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

After clicking on season you must make get request in your controller:

```
    public function changeSeason(Request $request){
       if($request->season == winter) {
            session(['season' => 'winter']);
       }
       if($request->season == summer) {
            session(['season' => 'summer']);
       }
    }
```

Then you can retrive the session:

```
session('season');
```

Comment: Hello, Adam. I'm sorry for the late answer. I don't get it. As far as I know I can put get request when I'm using forms, but in this case it's a link. So, how do I create that get request?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have 2 layouts for both the seasons, in you blade tempalate you can try this. Check value from the session and load the respective template. Laravel provides session facades to use in blade tempaltes.

```
@if(Session::get('season')=='WINTER')
    @include('layouts.winter')
@elif
    @include('layouts.summer')
@endif
```

Hope it solves your issue. In addition to @Adam Kozlowski answer.

Comment: Hello, arp. Yes, I understand that I have to use 2 layouts. That's fine, but how do I set the get request to create that season session? This is not a form, but only a link.